# Lodash: is there a way to uppercase a word keeping accents with lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash, uppercase, accent-sensitive

Is there a `lodash` function that would transform `"répété" => "RÉPÉTÉ"` instead of `"REPETE"`  as it's done by the `uppercase` function?

If not, what's an easy way to perform this in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `toLocaleUpperCase()`

```js
const str = 'répété';
const ret = str.toLocaleUpperCase();
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you have a native function called "toLocaleUpperCase()"

you can do this:

```js
const str = 'répété';
const ret = str.toLocaleUpperCase();
alert(ret);
```

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleUpperCase